# Weird DNS Resolving Problem

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu and I've really weird dns problem. The host command gives correct updated dns entires but firefox and ping command always gives old entries. My /etc/resolv.conf is correct and no other dns caching service running on Ubuntu. For example the following gives 1.2.3.4 as correct IP

```
host example.com
```

But when I do the following it gives old ip 1.1.1.1:

```
ping example.com
```

Same goes for firefox. How do I fix this mess?

Answer (score 3):

Ohh...
Ensure your hosts file is correct.. if your statically assigning something..
Flush the cache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
dig example.com
ping example.com
```

NB: note the server responding from dig.. if it doesnt respond correctly..
if all looks ok..
Flush the cache in firefox ( if its still not working )

Answer (score 1):

`host` does DNS lookups. `ping` and Firefox use the libc for lookups, which means that they're affected by the network service configuration. Look in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: I checked /etc/hosts and it got only two entires for 127.0.0.1 and ::1 and no entry for example.com. I also checked  /etc/host.conf and order is set to hosts,bind.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting the network completely?

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

and then trying to ping again?

Also, are you able to connect to the internet at all? Is your DNS server local or does it belong to a provider?

Comment: I did rebooted system, isp router, and we have our own caching dns server running on RHEL. This is only problem with specific Ubuntu box. I've just started PXE booting and reloading Ubuntu os :( (this is going on since last two weeks).